# indexed joining lists

Tags: r

Once lists start to get a bit nested I struggle a bit more with them (I think that others may struggle with nested lists too).  I have a list of lists that I want to put together in a certain format.  Here's an example of the list:

```
ms2 <- list(list(" question", c(" thin", " thick"), " one", c(" simple", 
" big")), list(" infer", " theme", c(" strategy", " guess", " inform"
), c(" big", " idea", " feel", " one")), list(
    "synthesi", c(" predict", " thin", " thick", " parts", " visual", 
    " determin", " schema", " connect", " background", " knowledge", 
    " strategy", " infer", " question", " importance"), NA_character_, 
    c(" things", " picture")), list(" visual", " strategy", " picture", 
    NA_character_), list(" question", " wonder", c(" them", " one"
), NA_character_), list(" predict", NA_character_, c(" think", 
" guess", " wonder"), NA_character_))
```

I want to combine the first three and last three lists together to get 2 lists of 4 vectors  each as in this below (this is just for the first list).

```
list(c("question", "infer", "synthesi", "visual"), 
    c("thin", "thick", "theme", "predict", "parts", 
        "visual", "determin", "schema", "connect", "backgraound",
        "knowledge", "strategy", "infer", "question", "importance", 
        "strategy"), 
    c("one", "strategy", "guess", "inform", "picture"), 
    c("simple", "big", "idea", "feel", "one", "things", "picture"))
```

Comment: The output you gave does not seem to match the description of what you want

Comment: Yeah this one was tougher to explain.  You guys got it though.  I should have just not explained it at all as I knew I wasn't doing a good job.  My example actually included one too many (1:4 rather than 1:3).

Comment: Scratch that the explanation was on the output was off. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
slice.it <- function(i,x) {
   slice <- lapply(x, `[[`, i)
   words <- unlist(slice)
   words <- words[!is.na(words)]
}

lapply(1:4, slice.it, ms2[1:3])
# [[1]]
# [1] " question" " infer"    "synthesi" 

# [[2]]
#  [1] " thin"       " thick"      " theme"      " predict"    " thin"      
#  [6] " thick"      " parts"      " visual"     " determin"   " schema"    
# [11] " connect"    " background" " knowledge"  " strategy"   " infer"     
# [16] " question"   " importance"

# [[3]]
# [1] " one"      " strategy" " guess"    " inform"  

# [[4]]
# [1] " simple"  " big"     " big"     " idea"    " feel"    " one"     " things" 
# [8] " picture"
```

Note that it does not match exactly the expected output you gave. Maybe you can help clarify these differences?

Comment: Both examples work and are generalizable.  For my understanding this answer is slightly more understandable in that it breaks each piece down.  Funny how I did a poor job at explaining and gave a wrong example (as GSee pointed out) yet you managed to figure out what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty close to the output you gave.  The difference is that I did not remove the leading space that all the words have in the input. If you remove the leading spaces, you won't have both " strategy" and "strategy" in the 2nd element of the result

```
lapply(1:4, function(i) {
    unique(na.omit(unlist(lapply(ms2, "[", i)[1:4])))
})
#[[1]]
#[1] " question" " infer"    "synthesi"  " visual"  
#
#[[2]]
#[1] " thin"       " thick"      " theme"      " predict"    " parts"     
#[6] " visual"     " determin"   " schema"     " connect"    " background"
#[11] " knowledge"  " strategy"   " infer"      " question"   " importance"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] " one"      " strategy" " guess"    " inform"   " picture" 
#
#[[4]]
#[1] " simple"  " big"     " idea"    " feel"    " one"     " things"  " picture"
```

Comment: you are correct my description doesn't match my output.  My apologies.  Despite that both you and Flodel provided answers that are generalizable. +1

Comment: Great. Glad you got it figured out.  Here's slightly different syntax that will give output identical to @flodel's: `lapply(1:4, function(i) { x <- unlist(lapply(ms2, "[", i)[1:3]); x[!is.na(x)] })`